# Making the user wait using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to make the user to wait for a certain amount of time (10 seconds). I know in JSP or in servlets we use the META tag `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3">`. Is there any way in Swing that we can make the user wait for some time. I am using Swing; I want to make the user wait for certain amount of time, and I want to display some information that will be fetched from the database. Is it possible through Swing?

Comment: Do you want to re populate some control some period of time or you want to reload whole form. any way using thread you can make content to load after 10 sec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SimpleTimer extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    private JLabel label;
    private Timer timer;
    private int counter = 10; // the duration
    private int delay = 1000; // every 1 second
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SimpleTimer()
    {
        super("Simple Timer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 65);
        label = new JLabel("Wait for " + counter + " sec");
        getContentPane().add(label);
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new SimpleTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            timer.stop();
            label.setText("The time is up!");
        }
        else
        {
            label.setText("Wait for " + counter + " sec");
            counter--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html)  is what you need!..

Answer (score 3):

Prior to WebSockets, HTTP servers could not send HTTP clients 'events'; the interactions were basically request-response. Many applications work around this problem using a (client-side) polling approach. The refresh meta-tag is one way of implementing polling.

Swing is very different -- you have the full strength of events. So the idea of making a user wait for a predetermined amount of time is usually the incorrect interaction. (Some sort of game/quiz/animation are a few of the exceptions, where simply waiting makes sense.)

You should design a Swing GUI that is functional and responsive while the results haven't been computed/received. Once the results are available, update a **model**, and fire an **event** advertising that the model has changed.

The model itself can do background computation, polling etc as necessary; that code is not swing specific. If you would like help on that aspect, consider looking for/asking about that separately on Stack Overflow.

Finally, remember that sleeping on the swing thread will make the UI unresponsive. And on a related note, any event fired by your model should be queued onto the Swing event thread. See [SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) about how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with threads. Using

```
   Thread.sleep(10000);
```

you can acheive it easily. You can get more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)