# Text not displaying on Jtogglebutton in java

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm making a minesweeper game. The problem im having is that i want to display a word on a toggle button. I've done that using setText method but when ever i run it the text is not displayed on the button when clicked.

```
package minesweeper;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Mine extends javax.swing.JFrame {

final int wid = 9,hei = 9,noOfbombs = 10;
JToggleButton[][] blocks = new JToggleButton[hei][wid];
int[][] blox = new int[hei][wid];

ActionListener listen = new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   boolean found = false;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < hei ; i++) {
         for (j = 0 ; j < wid ; j++) {
            if (e.getSource() == blocks[i][j]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
       if(found) break; 
    }
    blocks[i][j].setText("Writing");

 }
};


public Mine() {
    initComponents();

    for(int i = 0; i < hei ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < wid;j++)
        {
           blocks[i][j] = new JToggleButton();
           blocks[i][j].setSize(jPanel1.getWidth()/wid,jPanel1.getHeight()/hei);
           jPanel1.add(blocks[i][j]);  
           blocks[i][j].setLocation(j*jPanel1.getWidth()/wid, i*jPanel1.getHeight()/hei);
           blocks[i][j].addActionListener(listen);

        }
    }


}
private void resiz(){
    for(int i = 0;i<hei;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<wid;j++)
        {
           blocks[i][j] = new JToggleButton();
           blocks[i][j].setSize(jPanel1.getWidth()/wid, jPanel1.getHeight()/hei);
           jPanel1.add(blocks[i][j]);
           blocks[i][j].setLocation(j*jPanel1.getWidth()/wid, i*jPanel1.getHeight()/hei);

        }
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents()                 

private void jPanel1ComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                         
             resiz();        
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {
  //@override          
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Mine().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Mine() {
    initComponents();    
    for(int i = 0; i < hei ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < wid;j++)
        {
           blocks[i][j] = new JToggleButton();
           blocks[i][j].setSize(jPanel1.getWidth()/wid,jPanel1.getHeight()/hei);
           blocks[i][j].setLocation(j*jPanel1.getWidth()/wid, i*jPanel1.getHeight()/hei);
           blocks[i][j].addActionListener(listen);
           jPanel1.add(blocks[i][j]);  
        }
    }    
}
```

I think the fact that you add the listener *after* you add the `JToggleButton` is the cause of your problem.

**Edit #1:** I would also try changing this:

```
blocks[i][j].setText("Writing");
```

To this:

```
((JComponent) e.getSource()).setText("Writing");
```

**Edit #2:** Maybe try using `revalidate()` and `repaint()` like so:

```
((JComponent) e.getSource()).revalidate();
((JComponent) e.getSource()).repaint();
```

**Edit #3:** In case Edit #2 still doesn't work, your problem is probably that you are doing all your operations in the event dispatching thread. So the UI has no chance to update. You need to use a `SwingWorker` or better yet a Swing Timer (the one that has an Action callback) to make this work right. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662222/making-the-user-wait-using-swing/9662385#9662385) is an example of how to use a Swing Timer.
Good luck :)

Comment: I'll try again in a min

Comment: @AhsanAsif is the  if (e.getSource() == blocks[i][j])    ever "true" ? Did you check that you get found=true   at any time?